# Want to get maximum allowed Display Size programmatically for Android devices

Tags: android, display, android-windowmanager

Some Android devices support small display size and default, some support Large, Larger and Largest Display size.

In my case I'm trying to fetch the maximum Display size allowed for the particular device
for ex:
Device1: supported sizes small, Default.
here maximum density or size allowed is default.

Device2 : supported sizes small, default, large.
here maximum density or size supported is large and i want fetch this value

But with DisplayMatrics or Systemproperties i'm always getting default value.

Can some one please help to solve this or let me know is there any other way to find the maximum allowed display size.

Comment: What do you mean by default value?

Comment: If you open android Display Settings from Settings app you will see the Display supported sizes like Small, Default, Large, Larger, Largest.
this the default value